# GPU's fan grinding noise and how to fix it?

Tags: gpu, fan

This afternoon I hear a strange noise coming from my computer so I decided to take a video (I didn't know where it was coming from).

https://vid.me/HKBT

Later I discover it was coming from the GPU fan (MBA4412HF-A09) by removing its power cable.
I opened it and cleaned it...

[image]

I have done testing with a battery, here are the tests, one with the cover, one without.

https://vid.me/mGKC

https://vid.me/gXG0

But the noise is still there.

I lifted the sticker on the fan but I can't see the shaft...

I lifted the fan from the shaft but it's either fixed or stuck.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The cheapest solution.  Source a repacement fan for the fan or purchase the same card, marked "as for parts", and exchange the fan from that.  "I lifted the fan from the shaft but it's either fixed or stuck." - I am not sure what "it's" is exactly can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to lift the fan (the piece of plastic with the blades) from the bearing shaft... I can do that on the fan of my two laptops, so it was odd.

Comment: Google the part number you listed, a replacement fan is under $10 shipped from several sources. Replace the fan or replace the GPU, the sound is pretty obviously the shaft or bearings are worn out. If you can get to the shaft a little spray silicone might quiet it down for a while, but the sound is mechanical, it's just worn out.

Comment: Attempting to lift a fan off its bearing shaft can permanently shift the bushings, causing poor operation and premature wear. The shaft on a bushing fan should never be shifted. You me able to shift the fan and spindle out and in a bit, but if you don't put it back in precisely the right place (and how can you) you can accelerate bushing wear. Cheap fans can be lubricated to buy another month or two, but otherwise, you have to replace them. You can try centering it with respect to its range of motion and hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks David but is that so for my laptops' CPU fan as well?
They lifted off their bearing shaft VERY easily, as if they were meant to be lifted for cleaning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Ive had this problem before.

Its grinding where the shaft and windings are. This can come from manufacture defect even though it just happened (Mine when it happened was this), dust being a pain and getting into it (Rare unless you did the next reason), Or the common reason is cleaning the system with to high of pressure air blasting. People and sometimes even experts just blast air in as the fan spins. They are not made to go those speeds. This is a big killer of fans.

Side note: *For any reading to know what to do instead of blasting away (Since the OP may know this)... just place a pencil or lightly a finger on it making sure the fan doesn't spin while air blasts are done to remove dust.*

Since you don't mind pulling stuff apart as shown id just replace the fan. However when you install it use a thin dampener between it and this will further reduce noise.

After a bit of search this is what I mean:

[Fan Shim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhkYrzST7V4)

Ive found those fans on Newegg and Directron (Also for readers who just came here since im sure the OP knows already).

Now is it fixable? Not worth the time since youd need to rewind and then re-glue it back in. So unless you're into 7-8 hours of work just to save the fan for the same cost it is to replace, just replace it.