# Can I run my computer without my noisy graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card

My graphic card has a problem. For details [GPU's fan grinding noise and how to fix it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1171601/gpus-fan-grinding-noise-and-how-to-fix-it)

My question is can I turn on the computer without it? Would the computer work?

Computer
HP Pavilion 500-211el

Motherboard Model:                                                              Hewlett-Packard 2AF7

Motherboard Chipset:                                                            Intel H87 (Lynx Point)

Intel website says I don't have integrated graphics

https://ark.intel.com/products/75004/Intel-H87-Chipset

I thought "better ask" before trying it, better safe than sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to correct you: Intel website says your H-87 Chipset does not have integrated graphics.

Your H-87 Chipset might not have integrated graphics but your CPU certainly does. [HP Pavilion 500-211el](http://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c04089653) sports an [Intel® Core™ i7-4770 Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/75122/Intel-Core-i7-4770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) which comes with Intel® HD Graphics 4600. So, yes, you can turn on your computer without your graphic card and have image too. Plus, HP says your motherboard supports integrated graphics too.

Comment: Thanks Fleet Command. I'll check all CPU info, chipset info and motherboard info next time

Answer (score 1):

Your chipset is not your CPU, but I can understand you came to that conclusion. It provides functionality for I/O, as well as some motherboard functionality. The best, and most accurate, way to share your PC specs (if you're running Windows) is this.

1. hit the windows key
2. type `msinfo32` and hit enter
3. find the processor info

   - this should look like `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 740  @ 1.73GHz, 1730 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)`
   - you only need to write out the model number. In the case of this example, you would only need to type `Intel Core i7 Q740`
4. other parts to report

   - `System Summary` > Installed Physical Memory (RAM)
   - `Components` > `Display` > Adapter Type

Based on HP's site for that prebuilt, your CPU will have integrated graphics (aka iGPU). To use that, plug the monitor output into the back of the motherboard, rather than the back of your graphics card. This should be next to your USB ports, instead of their own area. Note that your gaming performance will not be as good if you're using the iGPU (probably).

If you want to become more familiar with PC hardware or you know someone that is, remove the graphics card from your PC. This will not negatively affect your PC.

Comment: Really grateful for your help Mitchell